# How to turn off the required message for drop-down list?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a form contains two radio buttons.  One is associated with a drop-down and the other is associated with a text-box.  If the user selects the second radio button (text-box), I would like to turn off the required message for the drop-down because when the user presses the 'Submit' button, the drop-down displays a message "Please select an item in the list."

BTW, I got it to work correctly if I just disabled the drop-down when the second radio button is selected but I was wondering if there is another way (maybe better) because when you disable the drop-down it changes it grays out.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Model:

```
public class EnrollmentModel : Controller
{
  ...
  public bool PriceOption { get; set; }

  [RequiredIf("PriceOption == true")]
  public string SelectedRatePlan { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RatePlans { get; set; }

  [RequiredIf("PriceOption == false")]
  public string CustomRate { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        @Html.Label("Price Option:")
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.PriceOption, true, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "comed", @class = "col-md-1" })
        @Html.Label("Use price from current rate plan")
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedRatePlan, new SelectList(Model.RatePlans, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "rateplans", style = "width:100px;", required = "Select Rate Plan" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.SelectedRatePlan, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.PriceOption, false, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "custom", @class = "col-md-1" })
        @Html.Label("Enter custom price")
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.CustomRate, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "customrate", @class = "form-control", style = "width:100px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.CustomRate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-link" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';" />
          &nbsp;
          <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that the field is optional in your model because bool cannot be null.
add "?" after "bool" or use "Nullable" instead of "bool"

```
 public bool? PriceOption { get; set; }
```

That question mark means this property can be null.

In this page, you can find how to implement a change event on the radio button:
https://devdojo.com/tutorials/how-to-detect-radio-box-change-with-jquery

and you can remove an attribute by using the following codes:

```
$("#selectElementId").removeAttr("required");
```

Comment: I made the suggested changed but didn't work.  I still get the "Please select..."

Comment: you also need to remove "required" attribute from "select" element.

Comment: in change event of radio button you can remove or add whatever attribute you want.

Comment: Just removing the "required" attribute from the "select" worked, made it work - the bool? didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: In the server side, you should get a validation error at least, because there is no data for "PriceOption". if you use the default MVC validation it will prevent you to submit the form. and also there is a logic issue, when you didn't set the bool property it will be "false" by default and it is wrong.

Comment: Make sure you check ModelState in your Action

Comment: Adding the `?` to the property did the job for me.